# Difference in c_str function specification between C++03 and C++11

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++03, c-str

In the C++ [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) of `c_str()` in `std::string` the following appears:

> **Return value**
>   Pointer to the underlying character storage.
>   `data()[i] == operator[](i) for every i in [0, size())` (until C++11)
>   `data() + i == &operator[](i) for every i in [0, size()]`   (since C++11)

I do not understand the difference between the two, except for the range increase by one element since C++11.

Isn't the former statement `data()[i] == operator[](i)` also true for the latter?

Comment: the previous wording allowed for copy on write implementations, which might have to make a copy for `c_str()`

Comment: I would say that `data()[size()]` is UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not in case of the C++11 implementation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Except for the range increment by one element since C++11, there is still a big difference between:

```
data()[i] == operator[](i)
```

and:

```
data() + i == &operator[](i)
```

That main difference is the `&` operator in the prototypes.

The old prototype, allowed for **copy** to be made when a write operation would occur, since the pointer returned could point to another buffer than the one holding the original string.

The other difference in the prototypes between `data()[i]` and `data() + i`, is not critical, since they are [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242017/whats-the-difference-between-ptri-and-ptr-i).

---

A difference between C++ and C++11 is that in the former, an `std::string` was not specified explicitly by the standard for whether it would have a null terminator or not. In the latter however, this is specified.

In other words: [Will std::string always be null-terminated in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077189/will-stdstring-always-be-null-terminated-in-c11) Yes.

Comment: Arguably, an implementation could reserve space for the terminator, and lazily null it from `c_str()`. Not that that would be a reasonable thing to do, of course.

Comment: Nah, it's an almost painfully pedantic point. Jus' saying. :)

Answer (score 9):

Note the closing bracket difference:

> [0, size()**)**
>
> [0, size()**]**

First stands for exclusive range (that is item at `size` index is not included) while second stands for inclusive range (that is item at `size` index is included)
Before C++ the precense of terminating null was not handled in this case, while in C++11 accessing character at `size()` position is well-defined.

As for difference between `data()[i] == operator[](i)` and `data() + i == &operator[](i)` the second one applies more restrictions on potential implementation. In first case a pointer to buffer returned by `data()` may be different from the pointer to buffer where a value the reference to which  returned by `operator []` is stored. This could happen when a new buffer was created after invocation of non-const-qualified operator[] of copied string.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C++11, it was unspecified whether the string data was null-terminated or not. C++11 says it must be null-terminated.

Comment: But why the notation difference from `data()[i]` to `data() + i`?

Comment: I thought VTT explained that - it's the difference difference between half-open and open ranges.

Comment: I don't get that. Isn't `data()[i]` identical to `*(data() + i)`?

Comment: But c_str already existed and had to run in constant time, wouldn't this imply that the null terminator is present?

Comment: @Nir All implementations I'm aware of provided it, but the C++98 Standard didn't specify that there must be one.